# How can play recording file while recording progress in android audio recorder

Tags: android

I want to play the audio recorder file while recording progress.

**OR**
Any other way to play the sound while recording

Comment: Yes, if you use `AudioRecord` and `AudioTrack`. Every time you read from the AudioRecord, write it to the AudioTrack as well as to disk (or to an encoder if you want compressed output).

Comment: Echo coming..whta will do

Answer (score 0):

You are getting echo because you are playing the audio through main speaker while recording.
Try to listening to the audio thru headphone while recording thru built in mic.
Also let me know the changes you made to accomplish the main task.

Comment: Would you care to share some source code?  May I see how you do this?  Is it just:  AudioTrack.play(); AudioRecord.startRecording();